# asserting string in clips

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips

I am trying to assert the value of name into a variable but when i assert it the value is coming in quotes and also with an extra space at the end.

```
   (defrule discount_amt_group 
    (exists (Student (age 14)(marks ?q&:(> ?q 40))))
    =>
    (bind ?name "")
    (do-for-all-facts ((?p Student))
                  (or (eq ?p:marks 80)
                     (eq ?p:marks 75)
                     (eq ?p:marks 90))
    (bind ?name (str-cat ?name ?p:name " "))
    (bind ?totalMarks (+ ?totalMarks ?p:marks)))
    (assert (StudOut(names ?name)))
```

the expected value will be (name Harry Ron Ginger) but now its coming as (name "Harry Ron Ginger ")
please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent the names as a multifield value rather than a string. You can use the create$ function to initially create an empty multifield value and then again to append values to it.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate Student
   (slot name)
   (slot age)
   (slot marks))
CLIPS>    
(deftemplate StudOut
   (multislot names)
   (slot totalMarks))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts Students
   (Student (name Harry) (age 14) (marks 80))
   (Student (name Ron) (age 15) (marks 75))
   (Student (name Ginger) (age 14) (marks 90))
   (Student (name Sally) (age 12) (marks 95)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule discount_amt_group 
   (exists (Student (age 14)(marks ?q&:(> ?q 40))))
   =>
   (bind ?name (create$))
   (bind ?totalMarks 0)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?p Student))
                     (or (eq ?p:marks 80)
                         (eq ?p:marks 75)
                         (eq ?p:marks 90))
      (bind ?name (create$ ?name ?p:name))
      (bind ?totalMarks (+ ?totalMarks ?p:marks)))
   (assert (StudOut (names ?name)
                    (totalMarks ?totalMarks))))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (Student (name Harry) (age 14) (marks 80))
f-2     (Student (name Ron) (age 15) (marks 75))
f-3     (Student (name Ginger) (age 14) (marks 90))
f-4     (Student (name Sally) (age 12) (marks 95))
f-5     (StudOut (names Harry Ron Ginger) (totalMarks 245))
For a total of 6 facts.
CLIPS>
```